# Caffe: opencv error

Tags: c++, opencv, python-3.x, opencv3.0, caffe

I've built opencv 3.0 from source and can run a few sample apps, build against the headers ok so I presume it's installed successfully.

I'm also using python3 and I now go to install and build caffe. I set a few variables in Makefile.config as I'm using the CPU due to having an AMD GPU and also Anaconda.

When I run make all I get this error:

```
$ make all
CXX/LD -o .build_release/examples/cpp_classification/classification.bin
/usr/bin/ld: .build_release/examples/cpp_classification/classification.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6imreadERKNS_6StringEi'
//usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:565: recipe for target '.build_release/examples/cpp_classification/classification.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/examples/cpp_classification/classification.bin] Error 1
```

from searching I think this is something to do with using openCV 3 but I'm not sure where to start looking for a solution. Any help?

And yes I'm one of the horde of inexperienced users looking to fiddle with the Google Inception learning technique.

Answer (score 15):

You can also add the `opencv_imgcodecs` to the MakeFile in line [187](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3140/files#diff-b67911656ef5d18c4ae36cb6741b7965L187), see this [pull](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3140).

Comment: adding `-lopencv_imgcodecs` worked great for my g++ compile.

Answer (score 8):

It could be that you are using OpenCV version 3.  If yes just uncomment the following line in your `Makefile.config`:

```
# OPENCV_VERSION := 3
```

So it will look like

```
OPENCV_VERSION := 3
```

You could verify the version currently in use by doing:

```
$ python
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.1.0-dev'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem report is very clear. There is a problem with linking library libraries.The reason may be the difference between 3.0 and 2.x.
You need to add

```
opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs
```

into LIBRARIES +=.

Answer (score 1):

I used `cmake` instead with the `-DBUILD_TIFF=ON` flag and got a successful build.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `Makefile.config` with the following 2 lines like this and it worked for me. Note that your opencv path **must be set before default path**!

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /home/young/Soft/openCV-3.3.1/include \
    /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /home/young/Soft/openCV-3.3.1/lib \
    /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround is to add `-lopencv_imgcodecs` flag when you're compiling your code.
This worked for me:
`g++ test.cpp -o test <Some flags> -lopencv_imgcodecs`